# Python netadd module on centOS

Tags: python, linux, sockets, python-2.7, centos6

I have a centOS server and I installed python2.7 on it...
I installed:

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools"
yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel
```

I also have a python script that uses netadd module...
but when I run my script I see the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dns_finder.py", line 4, in <module>
    from netaddr import *
ImportError: No module named netaddr
```

I installed:

```
yum install python-netaddr.noarch
```

Can you help what I can do exactly...?  :(
thank you very much

Comment: Does `dns_finder.py` use the system python? Check the first line of the the `dns_finder.py`.

Comment: I wrote it : #!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comment, you're using your custom version of Python; custom versrion does not use package installed using `yum`.

Use system version of python; Replace the following line:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

with

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: thank you but the next error is now dns.query and there is not in yum search dns.query

Comment: @Triumph, Install the package (maybe `dnspython` ?) to the system verison of python.

Comment: thank you..everything is solved   :) (http://www.onaxer.com/2011/02/02/enabling-dnspython-in-python/)